# AttributeError: 'CustomTreeCtrl' object has no attribute '_imageListNormal' exception

Tags: python, wxpython

I am getting following exception  in wxpython

AttributeError: 'CustomTreeCtrl' object has no attribute '_imageListNormal'

Could you please let me know how to resolve this.This issue is inconsistent.

Comment: Can you show as your code? What does "inconsistent" mean in your context?

Comment: I mean issue is Intermittant meaning Issue occurs 1 out of 50 case.

Comment: You should check what **you** did of special in that one case to get different behavior that in the other 49.

Comment: @joaquin - It can still be non-deterministic random case. I have seen this before. But we really need to see the code and exact line where the exception was raised.

Comment: Sorry Guys, I am not able find special case. Since All 50 Scenario's while testing are same ..I think this could be Timing issue while running the application!!. Let me know If I am wrong.